# Fix error in mp3 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, video-encoding, mencoder

I have an `mp3` file that plays OK on computer but there is a problem to play it on `mp3 player`.

ffmpeg shows this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i file.mp3
[mp3 @ 0x8de72a0] Invalid size in frame , skipping the rest of tag.
[mp3 @ 0x8de72a0] max_analyze_duration reached
[mp3 @ 0x8de72a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'file.mp3':
  Duration: 00:27:44.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 55 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 56 kb/s
```

Can I fix this problem with some utility? like `ffmpeg` or `mencoder`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MP3Diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/). It has a gazillion of tests and is able to fix many problems in MP3 files.

Comment: This is what I tried and didn't helped.