# How to fix mp3 with mp3diags on the command line

Tags: mp3

It's [been said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28295/fix-error-in-mp3-file) that `mp3diags` can be used to repair MP3 files. There's an old file that plays fine on Windows, but I noticed that something wasn't right because it would not let me edit properties like the title on Explorer (although iTunes could).

I installed it on Ubuntu WSL with `sudo apt install mp3diags` (1.5.01-1build1). I run it as follows:

```
mp3diags file.mp3
```

And I can see several errors, including:

```
- WARNING: ID3V2 tag has an APIC frame (which is used to store images), but the image couldn't be loaded. [0]
- WARNING: Error loading image in APIC frame. The frame is too short anyway to have space for an image. [27]
- ERROR: Invalid MPEG stream. Stream has fewer than 10 frames. [14627]
- ERROR: Invalid MPEG stream. Stream has fewer than 10 frames. [14642]
```

But I don't just want to see errors, I want to try to fix them. How do I do that?

Tried `mp3diags --help` and saw no option to fix. There's also no `man` page. The [documentation](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/030_users_guide.html) seems focused on the GUI version. Same thing when I look it up online. I specifically want to use the command line. If there's an alternative CLI tool, would also be happy to know about it. Thank you.

Comment: The GUI documentation you linked (as far as I can tell) does not mention fixing MPEG streams either - I doubt this is possible with `mp3diags` (or any program for that matter)

Comment: Regardless, I'd like to know how to at least try and see what message I get from the program. Thanks.

Comment: This was an example, I might have other files I want to fix...

Comment: Any update on how to do this?